# Gestor persistencia

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente parte de un código:

```
  public Assignatura obtenirAssignatura(int codiAssignatura) throws GestorException  {
       //TODO: completar metode. Caldra modficar la instruccio return
      ClientQuery query;
      try{
          query=session.query("for $a in doc(\"assignatures/assignatures.xml\")/collection(\"assignatures\")//assignatures/Assignatura[@codi = \""+codiAssignatura+"\"] return $a");
          String primerText=query.next();
          if(primerText==null){
              throw new GestorException(CLAU_INEXISTENT);
          }
          return Utilitats.obteAssignatura(primerText);
          }catch (IOException ex){
              throw new GestorException (ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gestors.GestorAssignatura.obtenirAssignatura(GestorAssignatura.java:93)
    at gestors.GestorAssignatura.inserir(GestorAssignatura.java:45)
    at TestGestor.ferAltes(TestGestor.java:96)
    at TestGestor.setUp(TestGestor.java:45)
```

las lineas que señala son:

java:93:

```
 query=session.query("for $a in doc(\"assignatures/assignatures.xml\")/collection(\"assignatures\")//assignatures/Assignatura[@codi = \""+codiAssignatura+"\"] return $a");
```

java: 45

obtenirAssignatura(as.getCodi());

no sé que puede ser por más ejemplos que miro veo que lo tengo bien.. :S

Comment: session es null

Comment: @Montse Mkd lo que puedes hacer es instanciar `GestorAssignatura asignatura = new GestorAssignatura();`

Comment: @Montse Mkd puedes mostrar que tienes obtenirAssignatura